# Parse error on AlaSQL library in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, alasql

I read a table, do some filtering and the results are in an object called "row".

```
    let row=[];
    vs.forEach((r,i)=>{
            if(dtv>=frv && dtv<=tov && id==r[0] && (r[12] == Suppliers[0] || r[12] == Suppliers[1] || r[12] == Suppliers[2]))   {
                   row.push(r);
                      }
    });
```

I am trying to write a query using ALASQL library in Google Apps Script.

```
    var alasql = AlaSQLGS.load();
    var res = alasql('SELECT A,B, SUM(C) FROM ? GROUP BY A,B',[row]);
```

I get the error "SyntaxError: Parse error" in the query line.

Any suggestions would be appreciated on how to resolve this.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is AlaSQL is meant to use clientside.  Google Apps Script runs on a server. [Reference](http://alasql.org/)

Comment: Could you please include your row data values, and your expected result for us to visualize your goal and probably replicate your issue.